# Chamar uma pagina via ajax Angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs

Meu codigo ajax:

```
$scope.CarregaMenuPrincipal = function (data) 
{
    var req = $http({ method: 'POST', url: '/Home/Index',data:{usuario: data.usuario },})
       .then(function (response) {
           response;
       }, function (response) {
          response;
       });
}
```

Meu codigo no Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(UsuarioModel usuario)
{
    if (usuario != null && usuario.ListaRegras != null)
    {
        return View(usuario);
    }
    else
       return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home", usuario);
}
```

Quando executa a linha return View(usuario), ele passa pela view criar toda a tela html porem se mantem na tela de login.cshtml e não chamar a tela index.cshtml. Alguém sabe como faço para redirecionar?

Comment: Você precisa fazer o redireccionado utilizando o próprio AngularJs dentro do seu then().

Comment: Fiz isso, porem a action Index ta recebendo valor null
 $scope.Logar = function () {
        var usuario = $scope.usuario;
        var req = $http({ method: 'POST', url: '/Home/Autenticar', data: { usuario: usuario }, })
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.usuario.usuario = response.data.dadosUsuario;
                if (response.data.msg == '') {
                    window.location.href = '/Home/Index/' + { usuario: usuario.usuario };} else {$window.alert(response.data.msg); }
            },
     function errorCallback(response) {
     });
    }

Comment: Sua Action esta recebendo null porque o Json que você esta passando não esta no formato correto para mapear para `UsuarioModel`. Seu model `UsuarioModel` tem uma propriedade chamada `usuario`?

Comment: Esta assim:    public class UsuarioModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Usuario { get; set; }
        public string Senha { get; set; }
        public int FuncionarioId { get; set; }
        public string FuncionarioNome { get; set; }
        public List<RegrasUsuarioModel> ListaRegras { get; set; }
    }